# Blurry text on link hover in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to create a blurry effect that will last e.g. 500 ms and then it goes back to normal in some animation that will last e.g. 250ms. So, if the user hover over the link it will animate a blurry/fuzzy effect on this link text and then goes back to normal.

Let's say I have this code:

```
<a class="link-to-blurry" href="http://example.com">Text to blurry on hover</a>
```

Can this be done using jQuery or some additional JavaScript plugin?

Comment: http://motyar.blogspot.ca/2010/04/blur-effect-with-css-and-jquery.html

Comment: @dmck yes, something like that , but I need an animation too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

CSS:

```
a, a:hover {
    color: black;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    text-decoration: none;      
}

.on {
    transition: text-shadow 500ms;
    -webkit-transition: text-shadow 500ms;
    -moz-transition: text-shadow 500ms;
    -ms-transition: text-shadow 500ms;
    -o-transition: text-shadow 500ms;
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
}

.off {
    transition: text-shadow 250ms;
    -webkit-transition: text-shadow 250ms;
    -moz-transition: text-shadow 250ms;
    -ms-transition: text-shadow 250ms;
    -o-transition: text-shadow 250ms;
    text-shadow: 0;
}
```

JS:

```
$('a').hover(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('off').addClass('on');
}, function(){
    $(this).removeClass('on').addClass('off');
});
```

Comment: Yes, thats nice, if there is only an animation twist to it, now it is not smooth. I guess I will need animation from jQuery to make the transition with e.g. fadeIn and fadeOut, or something like that.

Comment: @Derfder I'm sorry but I came out when I get back I try to prove something.

Comment: Hi, any progress? I already thumbs it up and I will tick it as the best answer too if you find out the way how to make the animation happen. Thanks in advance.